# Loading a very large table without a numeric ID from MySQL to S3

Tags: mysql, sqoop, bigdata, database

I'm trying to pump (with Sqoop) a large table (500GB in size with around 200M rows) in MYSQL to S3. However this table doesn't have a Key column which is numeric.

It has a combined primary key with 3 columns. I observed that sqoop cannot chunk the dataset evenly as the ID are not evenly distributed between min and max values. Rage queries in sqoop don't work well because that column is not indexed.

Is there a better way to do this with sqoop or any other technology?

P.S. I'm trying to output data as AVRO files

Comment: A 500GB table :o (I'm pretty sure that even the entirety of the Stack Exchange *database* isn't that large). What's in the table that makes it so big?

Comment: Its transaction data :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table that has multi-column key, you need to specify the range manually using --split-by argument using a different column. Sqoop does not support multi columns.

Comment: Another case of 3rd party software getting in the way?